# Is there a way to upload, rename, then download a file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, file

Is there any HTML and JavaScript code to have a user upload a file, then the code will rename it, and automatically download it to the user's computer? I would be doing this on [repl](https://repl.it), not on a server I have if that helps.
I will convert a .zip file to a .mcpack file and back.

Comment: Related - if you're *uploading* something, there is implicitly some sort of server involved, which has to be running something that will take the upload and process it. You could write your server in JavaScript (and run using a runtime like Node.js) to fulfill your requirement of *only* HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @esqew that's completely and absolutely totally without question incorrect

Comment: @bluejayke Can you elaborate on what about my comment is incorrect? Will delete and re-add if that is in fact the case.

Comment: @esqew "you're uploading something, there is implicitly some sort of server involved" not true, the OP is obviously talking about selecting a file and editing it in the browser, no server is necessary here

Comment: @bluejayke I’m confused on how you arrived at that “obvious” conclusion when the OP explicitly states that “a user [will] **upload** a file” and subsequently “**download** it to the user’s computer”. Can you point to anything in my comment specifically that is “absolutely totally without question incorrect”?

Comment: @esqew user explicitly states "I would be doing this on repl, not on a server I have if that helps." Upload is obviously a borrowed term, and you don't need a server to "download" from the browser to computer

Comment: @esqew if he meant download from a remote server to his client side connection, he could have said just "download", the fact that he added the words "**to the user's computer**" implies the main thing is to get it on the actual computer file system, regardless of the original source

Comment: @bluejayke At the risk of being bogged down in semantics, I have to disagree on this. The dictionary definition of “download” is to “copy (data) **from one computer system to another, typically over the Internet**.” I would think with enough configuration a Repl.it can be set up to perform just that, as the OP has asked for in their original question. If they didn’t intend this meaning, I would invite them to edit their question to be more specific about their requirements.

Comment: @esqew obviously download and upload are borrowed terms dude, the OP said he's not using a server. What other words should he have used to describe his case?

Comment: @esqew first result on Google, just transferring in general
transitive verb

computers
: to transfer (data, files, etc.) from one location (such as a large computer or the cloud) to another (such as a smaller computer, smartphone, or storage device)

Comment: @esqew thefreedictionary says download
To take data into a computer from an outside source, such as the Internet or a floppy disk.       -----you can also download something from a phone to a computer via USB, the browser is like a virtual phone, computer system is like computer, transferring it from cache of browser to persistent memory is similar to transferring a file from USB drive to main hard disk

Comment: @bluejayke In the edits to the original question, I would invite the OP to include a more specific description of what they’re intending; “How can I rename and save a copy of a file from the local file system using only in-browser JavaScript?” would be closer to what i would expect to describe the requirements as you’ve interpreted them here, not precluding the additional effort required to bring the question back on-topic. (In observance of SO’s guidelines of avoiding extended discussions in comments, this will be my last response in this thread and we will just have to agree to disagree.)

Comment: @esqew to read the data from user's disk, it has to be "*uploaded*"  to the computer's memory. Then to save the data that is in memory to the user's disk is commonly called to "*download*" it.

Answer (score -1):

To write and download files with JavaScript, use object URLS, Blobs, and `<a>` elements. To upload, use `<input>` type `"file"`.

Example:

```js
f. onchange=function () {
  oy.href=URL.createObjectURL(f.files[0])
  oy.download="yo new name new game here.html"
  oy.click()
  oy.href=""
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id=f>
<a id=oy></a>
```

Comment: Better wait a bit before changing the `href`, also, would be good to `revokeObejctURL` the resulting blob:// URI and finally, don't be afraid of adding links to docs in your asnwers (and to format it correctly next time...)

Comment: @kaloido hi I'm on mobile do you know how to format correctly on Android chrome browser?